# Using submodel within model in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, clip, iterator

I have two databases 175 shapefiles each I want to clip each one of them using the corresponding shapefile from the second database .. as I can't use two iterators I have to do a nested submodel within a model.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Are you using the ModelBuilder with ArcMap, the ModelBuilder with ArcGIS Pro, or something else?

Comment: Perhaps review some of these Qs&As: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bmodelbuilder%5d%20submodel

Comment: You need to add more information to your question, this could all be done with one iterator if you explained what your data naming convention was? It's not clear what you have, for example does the corresponding clip featureclass always overlap the to be clipped featureclass?